# What's the best Regular Expression to use for returning some phone numbers, but not all?

Tags: regex

I'm new to Regular expressions and working on something that will return all UK phone numbers with an area code beginning `01`, `02`, `03` or `07` only. It has to not look up `08` or `09`. It also  has to take in to account the different grouping styles too. But here's the kicker... it's got to be 80 characters or less.

This was my best shot:

```
(01|02|03|07|44\D*1|44\D*2|44\D*3|44\D*7|)(\d\D*){9}
```

The problem is that it's returning any 9 digit or less number and I can't figure out why.

Any help would be grand!

Comment: Is the empty `or |` at the very end of your first group intentional? If not, then there's your problem.

Comment: Can you give some examples of numbers it should match and ones it shouldn't?

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistype here. In my program it reads: (01|02|03|07|44\D*1|44\D*2|44\D*3|44\D*7)(\d\D*){9}

Comment: @RobEarl So it should match 0123 456 7890 or 01 234 567890 (or any placement of spaces, or substitution of spaces for non-numeric characters like 0123-456-7890) but should allow 0823 456 7890 etc

Comment: Regular expressions are not the answer to everything. Consider writing a simpler regexp that matches *all* phone numbers, then rejecting numbers that you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(01|02|03|07|44\D*1|44\D*2|44\D*3|44\D*7)` is matching either `0` or `44\D*` followed by `1`, `2`, `3` or `7` which simplifies to:

```
(?:44\D*|0)[1237]
```

Putting that with the rest gives:

```
(?:44\D*|0)[1237](\D*\d\D*){9}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/oKEaedsP5KIY1G4r)

Comment: that's a definite space saver and an elegant solution. Seems to be working just fine too. Thanks!